# When using setter function inside a setInterval loop, clearInterval is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval, use-state

Basically, I was trying to make a counter that started counting the number of seconds as soon as I pressed start button and stopped counting when I pressed stop button and keep this stored in **sec**.

When I press the start button a handleStart function gets triggered which sets start variable to 1. Also, a setInterval starts repeating (every second) a setter function that increases **sec** by one. This setInterval also has a conditional statement which clears the setInterval when start becomes 0;

When I press stop button another function handleStop gets triggered setting start to 0. If setInterval is being run, it should see that start is 0 now and should clear the setInterval which should stop updating **sec** variable/state. But this is not working. When I log start it is still 1, even after pressing stop variable. If I log start in handleStop function, it logs as 0 but this is not reflecting in the further log statements of handleStart function.
Also, when I comment out the `setSec((prev)=> {return prev+1})`  line in handleStart function, everything works fine (the setInterval gets cleared after pressing stop button), so I guess there is something about useState functionality that I don't understand.
Can someone tell me what's wrong?

```
export default function Bug() {
    let start = 0
    let [sec, setSec] = useState(0)
    let repeat

    function handleStart() {
        start = 1
        repeat = setInterval(() => {
            setSec((prev) => { return prev + 1 })
            console.log(start);
            if (start === 0) {
                clearInterval(repeat)
            }
        }, 100);
    }

    function handleStop() {
        start = 0
        //clearInterval(repeat) //this clearInterval is not working either
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <p>{sec}</p>
            <button onClick={handleStart}>Start</button>
            <button onClick={handleStop}>Stop</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Sorry if such a question has already been answered here. I tried to search a similar question but couldnt find one.

Comment: why do you need to clear the interval inside the callback for `setInterval` if you're clearing  it inside `handleStop`.

Comment: I missed to comment one of them out. But still, none of the clearInterval is working.

Comment: `repeat` gets reinitialized on each render so after the first tick doesn't hold a reference to the interval anymore. If you want to handle it this way, either use a Ref, clear it in the callback, or use the render lifecycle to manage the state of the timer.

Comment: Move `let repeat` to a place outside of your functional component

Comment: @devnull69, that's not a good suggestion. The component should contain relevant logic

Comment: @devnull69 moving let repeat outside of the functional component is working. Thanks.

Comment: @pilchard I will have to study all that. I will try that out once I study those. Thanks for directing me though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `repeat` variable does not persist between renders, so every time you called `setSec` it re-renders.

One option would be to use the same idea as your timer variable to store your repeat variable.

```js
const Bug = () => {
    const [sec, setSec] = useState(0)
    const [repeat,setRepeat] = useState()

    const handleStart = () => {
        setRepeat(setInterval(() => {
            setSec((prev) => { return prev + 1 })      
        }, 1000));
    }

    const handleStop = () => {
    
        clearInterval(repeat)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <p>{sec}</p>
            <button onClick={handleStart}>Start</button>
            <button onClick={handleStop}>Stop</button>
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Bug/>,document.getElementById("root"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha256-32Gmw5rBDXyMjg/73FgpukoTZdMrxuYW7tj8adbN8z4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha256-bjQ42ac3EN0GqK40pC9gGi/YixvKyZ24qMP/9HiGW7w=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>var { useReducer, useEffect, useState, useRef, useCallback } = React</script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I think a ref would be even more appropriate here